# Can predicate and propositional logic be 'mixed'?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

**Motivation**

I wanted to write out a simple statement from linear algebra in a very formal, predicate logic way. The statement is that given two vector spaces $V \subset W$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$, $V$ is a subspace iff for any two vectors, any linear combination of them is contained in $V$.

I initially wrote $$\forall a \in V \forall b \in V \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F} \forall \beta \in \mathbb{F} \big(V \text{ is a subsapce iff } a\alpha + b\beta \in V\big)$$

I realised this was wrong, and it should be (as confirmed by this set of [notes](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/4063-5023/4063-5023-l02.pdf) I found)$$V \text{ is a subsapce iff } \forall a \in V \forall b \in V \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{F} \forall \beta \in \mathbb{F} \big( a\alpha + b\beta \in V\big)$$

It felt wrong in the first instance that the universal quantifiers extend over the statement that $V$ is a subspace.

**Question**

However, my issue is with proving these two are different. The way I see it, it's akin to trying to showing that $$\forall x P(x) \iff Q \text{ and } \forall x (P(x) \iff Q)$$ are different statements. Here I write $P(x)$ to be analogous to arbitrary vectors/scalars, over which we use a universal quantifier, and I write $Q$ as a statement that is independent of the variable $x$, to represent the statement that a vector is a subspace. To my mind, $Q$ is like a propositional statement, that is either simply either true or false.

But I am failing to to prove the two are not equivalent statements (I also tried showing that they ARE the same statements). In particular, I tried writing out truth tables, but got stuck and came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887262/how-are-quantifiers-managed-in-truth-tables) post which explains that quantifiers do not work with truth tables.

**Are these statements equivalent? And how do you go about proving it?** (I realise my discussion of the logic here is likely shaky at best, so apologies if I'm under obvious misconceptions.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that these statements are different.

The quickest way to see this is by looking at the claim

$$
\forall a,b \in V . \forall \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F} . (V \text{ is a subspace} \iff \alpha a + \beta b \in V)
$$

If this is true, then (basically by definition) we should have

$$
(V \text{ is a subspace} \iff \alpha a + \beta b \in V)
$$

for every choice of $a,b \in V$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}$. (Do you see why?)

In particular, this must be true when $a,b = 0$ and $\alpha, \beta = 0$. But in this case the claim reads

$$
(V \text{ is a subspace} \iff 0 \in V)
$$

which we know is false!

---

Said in the more abstract terms you adopts later, you're exactly right that

$$
\forall x \in X. (P(x) \iff Q) \quad \quad (1)
$$

is *different* from

$$(\forall x \in X . P(x)) \iff Q \quad \quad (2)$$

and the same argument works (as long as the domain $X$ has more than one element).

In formula $(1)$ we're saying that $P(x) \iff Q$ is true for every $x \in X$. So in particular, this tells us that $P(x_1) \iff Q \iff P(x_2)$ so that $P$ is constant on its domain $X$.

In formula $(2)$ we're saying that $Q$ is true exactly when $P(x)$ is always true. This is what we usually want to talk about.

---

But how can we formally prove that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are different? We need to exhibit a *countermodel*. We actually already have a countermodel from our first example of vector subspaces, but here's a small one you can really get your hands on:

Let $X = \{a,b\}$, with $P(a) = \top$, $P(b) = \bot$, and $Q = \bot$.

- Can you show that this model thinks $(1)$ is false?
- Can you show that this model thinks $(2)$ is true?
- From here, conclude that $(1)$ and $(2)$ must not be provably equivalent. If they were, they would have to be equivalent in all models, but here we've built a model where they differ.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: The idea of a countermodel is new to me, so this is excellent! Thank you!